# Problem with Union and Intersection

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following:

```
list={{a,b,c},{c,d,e},{d,e,f},...{x_,y_,z_}};
```

I would like to apply `Union` on the elements of the list in the following way

```
Union[{a,b,c},{c,d,e},{d,e,f},...{x_,y_,z_}];
```

The problem `Union[list]` does not return the desired result when applied on `list`. Please consider the following example:

```
list={{10,2,3},{2,3,4},{2,3,50}};
Union[list]
```

The same problem occures with `Intersection`.

```
(* Out={{10,2,3},{2,3,4},{2,3,50}} *)
```

Instead of

```
Union[{10,2,3},{2,3,4},{2,3,50}]
(* Out={2,3,4,10,50} *)
```

Comment: You're looking for `Apply`?

Comment: `Union@Flatten@list`

Comment: `Apply`works. Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Apply[Union, list]
```

which can be written in short form as

```
Union@@list
```

Answer (score 6):

`Union` eliminates duplicate elements in a list, or duplicate sublists in a list of lists.

```
In[9]:= list = {{a, a, a}, {a, a, a}, {d, e, f}};
        Union[list]

Out[10]= {{a, a, a}, {d, e, f}}
```

In your example,

```
list={{10,2,3},{2,3,4},{2,3,50}};                      
Union[list]
```

even though parts of the sublists are the same, no sublist was a complete duplicate of any other sublist. So there was nothing for `Union` to do.

Comment: +1 for the explanation **why** the OP's example does not behave as expected.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE and thanks for taking the time to explain this.  Please consider registering your account so your reputation score will be preserved and you can access to more features of the site.

Answer (score 5):

Just stir things up, you can also do the following:

```
Union[Sequence@@list]
```

It uses the same function referenced (Map), but makes forces the problem to look like you were expecting:

```
Union[{a,b,c},{c,d,e},{d,e,f},...{x_,y_,z_}];
```