# I keep writing functions like this one: subtract[{a_, b_}] := Subtract[a, b]

Tags: functions

(Edited to provide an example)

Recently I have found myself writing silly functions like the following, which is just a new arity of Subtract in which the arguments are inside a list.

`subtract[{a_, b_}] := Subtract[a, b]`

If I were adding that variant to one of my own functions, I would use the same name, and would feel more comfortable about it.

I feel sure I should not need to do this for system functions, yet these variants are very convenient when I am working with lists.

There is probably some elementary principle of Mathematica coding that I have failed to absorb. What could it be?

Example:

`pairsOfPositions = {{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}, {{g, h, i}, {j, k, 
    l}}, {{m, n, o}, {p, q, r}}};
differences = Map[subtract, pairsOfPositions, {1}];`

where the desired result for differences is

`{ {a - d, b - e, c - f}, 
  {g - j, h - k, i - l}, 
  {m - p, n - q, o - r} }`

Comment: [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)?

Comment: Proposed duplicates: [(10833)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10833/121),
[(46238)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/121)

Comment: My question is supposed to be about items embedded in a list. Maybe Apply would help, but I don't yet understand how.

Comment: @RalphDratman does not `Subtract @@@ pairsOfPositions` give the output you want?  If so you just need to take the time to understand `Apply`.  If this is not the result you want or you chose a narrow example please edit the question to explain.

Comment: Yes, thank you Sir Wizard, Subtract @@@ pairsOfPositions does work. Thank you so much. I will as you suggested look more deeply into Apply.

Comment: I feel dumb about asking such a simple question and getting such an apparently easy answer. Believe it or not, I use Mathematica frequently and effectively, but, as with most computer languages (for me), there are areas where my mind refuses to latch on. For me this happens with the inner parts of lists. Maybe there is a LIS gene which I lack.

Comment: @Ralph Not only do we all have those moments, but lots of things in *Mathematica*, and the rest of life really, look simple *after* you understand. :-)

Comment: @RalphDratman `Apply[Subtract]` is more or less equivalent to your `subtract` function.  This syntax is available since v10.  Try `Apply[Subtract][{a,b}]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Subtract @@ {a, b}
(* a - b *)
```