# How can I construct a string pattern from a list of patterns?

Tags: string-manipulation

Is it possible to construct a string pattern from a list of strings?

```
With[{patLst = {"abc", "bcd"}, str = "zabc"},
    StringMatchQ[
        str,
        ___~~("abc" | "bcd")~~__ (* How can I construct this dynamically from patLst? *)
    ]
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Alternatives @@ pathLst`. You can always use `FullForm` on that you want to get and, well do this.

Comment: It seems it may be marked as a duplicate of: [How do I convert an argument list to a list of arguments?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10833/5478)

Comment: I have no problem with the question being marked as a duplicate.  But, just for the record, I was aware of `Apply` but not of `Alternatives`.  It was the latter that was holding me up.

Comment: I see, well you may be right about that it is not the best candidate. Will come back later, don't have time to search better but there definitely is one.