# Intersection of all sublists of a list

Tags: syntax

I want to get the intersection of all sublists of list in an easy way.

```
list = {{a,b,c},{d,e,a},{c,a,f}]}
Intersection[list[[1]],list[[2]],list[[3]]] 
Intersection[list]
```

The first Intersection command works well (it gives {a}). But **the second one does not work**. I understand that there's a syntax error (*list* is a list of lists, but *Intersection* only takes individual lists. However, there must be a simple way around it? In my case, list has more than 3 sublists which makes it hard to write them all down.

Thanks

Comment: Simply : `Apply[Intersection, list]` (or `Intersection @@ list`)

Comment: Please note that `list = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, a}, {c, a, f}]}` has a mistaken `]`

Comment: Also a duplicate of: [(10833)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10833/121)  (I had to pick only one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by *Sjoerd C de Vries* and *andre* an easy way is to replace the head of your list with `Intersection` by using `Apply` (i.e, `@@`)

```
Intersection @@ list

(* {a} *)
```

Comment: IMHO `Intersection @@ list` would be easier.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries IMO you are 100% correct :) Answer edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments :
`Apply[Intersection, list]` (or `Intersection @@ list`)