# Pure function: using T[[#]] where # indicates a position

Tags: syntax, functional-style

When using `T[[#]]` in which `#` indicates a position, how do you pass on the position `#` (which is a list) to ensure that the intended argument `#` is used properly in the context `T[[#]]` (which requires the list brackets of the position not to be included)?

Example: the position `{1,2,2}` should be used as `T[[1,2,2]]` (where the list brackets must be dropped for proper use). How is this achieved?

It is not possible to chop the head off the list as each expression needs to have a head. One possibility it to use `T[[#[[1]],#[[2]],#[[3]] ]]` However, if the length of the list is not known, this should involve `T[[#[[1]],...,#[[Length[#]]]` which I assume is not proper Mathematica code. How is this case addressed?

Comment: Linked topic should address your question, let me know if you disagree. Another related one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10833/5478